# dialog with Listview setonitemclicklistener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a dialog showing a list of items with a checkbox.
If an item is clicked the checkbox should be set.
when the dialog is closed, the selected item should be taken.

The setOnItemClickListener doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_replace_tv"
            style="@style/TextViewStyleTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/replace" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/Dropdown" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_replace_item_lv"
            android:divider="@color/Dropdown"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code of the dialog:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        DevAction action = replaceItemListener.getAction();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_replace_item, null);

        // Text
        TextView messageTv = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_replace_tv);
        String message = getString(R.string.replace);
        message += " " + action.getItem().getSupplierRef();
        message += " " + getString(R.string.with);
        messageTv.setText(message);


        // List view
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_replace_item_lv);
        final CheckItemAdapter adapter = new CheckItemAdapter(getActivity(), action.getReplacements());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view12, i, l) -> adapter.setSelectedIndex(i));

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.replace))
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), null)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
            Button posBtn = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            posBtn.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
                replaceItemListener.onReplace(action, adapter.getSelectedItem());
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            });
        });

        return alertDialog;
    }
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class CheckItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private List<DevAction> dataList;
        private int selectedIndex = 0;

        public CheckItemAdapter(Activity activity, List<DevAction> dataList) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        }

        public void setData(List<DevAction> data) {
            this.dataList = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void setSelectedIndex(int position) {
            boolean refresh = position != selectedIndex;
            this.selectedIndex = position;
            if (refresh) notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public DevAction getSelectedItem() {
            if (dataList != null && (selectedIndex >= 0 && selectedIndex < dataList.size())) {
                return dataList.get(selectedIndex);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            AppCompatCheckBox checkBox;
            AppCompatTextView codeTv;
            AppCompatTextView locationTv;
            AppCompatTextView descriptionTv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return dataList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_checkbox_item, parent, false);

                viewHolder.checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_cb);
                viewHolder.codeTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_code_tv);
                viewHolder.locationTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_location_tv);
                viewHolder.descriptionTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_description_tv);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            DevAction action = (DevAction) getItem(position);
            if (action != null) {
                DevItem item = action.getItem();
                DevStockLoc loc = action.getLocation();

                if (item != null && loc != null) {
                    viewHolder.codeTv.setText(item.getSupplierRef());
                    viewHolder.locationTv.setText(loc.getLocationString());
                    viewHolder.descriptionTv.setText(item.getDesc(ctx().getLoggedUser().getLanguage()));
                }

                viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(position == selectedIndex);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

}
```

Thanks already for any ideas/help or suggestions on how to tackle this differently/better.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the adapter to this (using recyclerview now as suggested by Ralph):

```
public class CheckItemAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckItemAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DevAction> dataList;
    private int selectedIndex = 0;
    private DevAction currentlySelectedItem;
    private final Context context;

    public CheckItemAdapter2(Context context, List<DevAction> dataSet) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataSet;

        currentlySelectedItem = dataList.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_item_checkbox_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final AppCompatCheckBox checkBox;
        private final AppCompatTextView codeTv;
        private final AppCompatTextView locationTv;
        private final AppCompatTextView descriptionTv;

        DevAction resultItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_cb);
            codeTv = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_code_tv);
            locationTv = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_location_tv);
            descriptionTv = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_item_description_tv);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedIndex);
                    selectedIndex = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(selectedIndex > RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        DevAction clickedDataItem = dataList.get(selectedIndex);
                        currentlySelectedItem = clickedDataItem;
                    }
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedIndex);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        viewHolder.resultItem = dataList.get(position);

        if (viewHolder.resultItem != null) {
            DevItem item = viewHolder.resultItem.getItem();
            DevStockLoc loc = viewHolder.resultItem.getLocation();

            if (item != null && loc != null) {
                viewHolder.codeTv.setText(item.getSupplierRef());
                viewHolder.locationTv.setText(loc.getLocationString());
                viewHolder.descriptionTv.setText(item.getDesc(ctx().getLoggedUser().getLanguage()));
            }

            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(position == selectedIndex);
        }



        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {                
                if (isChecked) {
                    if(selectedIndex == viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                        // was already checked: ok
                    } else {
                        // new item checked                       
                        selectedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                        currentlySelectedItem = dataList.get(selectedIndex);
                        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(position == selectedIndex);

                        notifyDataSetChanged(); // can this be done otherwise?

                    }
                } else {
                    if(selectedIndex == viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                        // was already checked: keep checked
                        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    } else {
                        // ok
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (int) dataList.size();
    }

    public DevAction getSelectedItem() {
        return currentlySelectedItem;
    }

}
```

It allows for only one checkbox to be checked, so only 1 selected item. It does not matter whether the checkobox or the item is clicked.

Probably there are things that could be done differently/better?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a recycler view. Inside the recycler view adapter you can keep a list of all the selected items which could be retrieved via a public function.

Assuming your requirement is for multi-select, take a look at my adapter below.

```
class SellVariantAdapter(
    private val valuesList: List<VariantsItem>,
    private val onItemClick: (Boolean)->Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SellVariantAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
    private var lastSelectedIndex = -1
    private var currentlySelectedItem: VariantsItem? = null 

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemSellVariantValueBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(valuesList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = valuesList.size
    
    fun getSelectedValue() = currentlySelectedItem

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemSellVariantValueBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        fun bind(variant: VariantsItem) {
            binding.apply {
                displayText.text = variant.variant

                isSelected.isChecked = variant == currentlySelectedItem

                isSelected.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
                    if (event.action == ACTION_UP) {
                        root.performClick()
                    }
                    return@setOnTouchListener true
                }

                root.setOnClickListener{
                    onClickSingleSelect(variant)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun onClickSingleSelect(variant: VariantsItem) {
            binding.apply {
                currentlySelectedItem = variant
                notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedIndex)
                lastSelectedIndex = bindingAdapterPosition
                notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedIndex)
                onItemClick(isSelected.isChecked)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the list of selected items via `getSelectedValues()` on your button click and remove them from your data.

I had written this in Kotlin, hence wasn't able to provide the same in Java, hope it helps!

#### Update:

Hi, as per you're comment I've updated the code for single item selection.

Comment: Hi Ralph, Thanks for the feedback. The fact of the matter is that the list shows a checkbox for every item, but only one item should be allowed as checked and passed as a result to the caller. So, no multi-select required. I think the idea was (it is code inherited from other developer) to have 1 item checked, and if another gets checked, the previous gets unchecked.

Comment: Hi @Nopunintended, take a look at the updated code. I've updated the logic for single item selection. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the input. I got it working. I add my new adapter class in my original answer. It was a bit hard for me to understand the kotlin.